# Unit test RedirectToRouteResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, redirecttoaction, redirecttoroute

I have the following code in my controller:

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult MyMethod()
    {
        ...
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
    }
}
```

I'd like to unit test this redirect (RedirectToRouteResult).
I've done it this way:

```
Assert.IsTrue(result.RouteValues.ContainsKey("action"));
Assert.IsTrue(result.RouteValues.ContainsKey("controller"));
Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.RouteValues["action"].ToString());
Assert.AreEqual("Dashboard", result.RouteValues["controller"].ToString());
```

So I need four asserts to test my RedirectToRouteResult.
Is there any more efficient way?

Comment: id also assert.instanceoftype since you have it returning actionresult

Comment: Yes, I do it this way: RedirectToRouteResult result = (RedirectToRouteResult)controller.Captcha(loginUseraccount);
If it's not an RedirectToRouteResult an exception is thrown and the test fails.

Comment: I know multiple asserts are generally frowned upon, but I use the principle that you're testing for one "thing". In this case, you meet the general idea.

Answer (score 8):

There is a more efficent way since you don't need to test these two lines

```
Assert.IsTrue(result.RouteValues.ContainsKey("action"));
Assert.IsTrue(result.RouteValues.ContainsKey("controller"));
```

Those are assertions for code that you have not written. You have to trust that those who writes that code have there own unit tests. If against all odds the first two lines would be faulty, your two final assertions would fail.